# How to find the type for a class created with Dojo declare?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am creating an object using a `"class"` define using `declare` in Dojo.

I need to check the type (class name) for that object.

At the moment I am using property `declaredClass` in the prototype.

Is `declaredClass`  the proper way to check the type. Any better way or method in Dojo?

```
 define(["dojo/_base/declare", "my/Person"], function(declare, Person){
      return declare(Person, {
        constructor: function(name, age, residence, salary){
          // The "constructor" method is special: the parent class (Person)
          // constructor is called automatically before this one.

          this.salary = salary;
        },

        askForRaise: function(){
          return this.salary * 0.02;
        }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you're going to try to do. If you need to check if the class is of a certain type, you can use the following:

```
myObject.isInstanceOf(Person);
```

For example:

```js
require(["dojo/_base/declare"], function(declare) {
    var Mammal = declare(null, {
        constructor: function(name) {
            this.name = name;  
        },
        sayName: function() {
            console.log(this.name);
        }
    });
    var Dog = declare(Mammal, {
        makeNoise: function() {
            console.log("Waf waf");
        }
    });

    var myDog = new Dog("Pluto");
    myDog.sayName();
    myDog.makeNoise();

    console.log("Dog: " + myDog.isInstanceOf(Dog));
    console.log("Mammal: " + myDog.isInstanceOf(Mammal));
});
```

This will return `true` twice, because `myDog` is an instance of `Dog` and also an instance of `Mammal`.